# Head HTML appearing in page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm referencing some external scripts for =< IE8 like this:

```
<!--[if lte IE8]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

However, looking at my site in =< IE8, the files are referenced successfully, but I can literally the text:  `<!--[if lte IE8]><![endif]-->` in the page, just above the body!

Is this a common error? The code is the last thing in my `<head></head>`.

It's a Ruby on Rails app and I'm using Bootstrap 3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
<!--[if lte IE8]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

To this:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

It's because there is no space between `IE` and `8`. Remember to always put a space there in between.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need a space between 'IE' and the version number, it might be the cause.

Comment: I think you're correct, as seen here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a space between IE and 8, likewise: `<!--[if lte IE 8]><![endif]-->`